# Getting a Stream from a resource file / content

Tags: c#, asynchronous, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is this the correct/only way of getting a **Stream** from a resource file?

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(fullPath);

    StorageFile storageFile = 
      await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.
        GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

    IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType randomAccessStream = 
      await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();

    IInputStream resourceStream = (IInputStream)
      randomAccessStream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
```

All my other sources (http and local storage) return a Stream object, and it is painful to have to if-else code that uses one or the other.

I've also tried to just create a MemoryStream out of it, but I can't even find a way to get the bytes out... Please help.

```
    uint size = (uint)randomAccessStream.Size;
    IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(size);
    await randomAccessStream.ReadAsync(buffer, size, 
      InputStreamOptions.None);

    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer); // error takes byte[] not IBuffer
```

IInputStream.ReadAsync() when reading from resource:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream.readasync.aspx

while Stream.Read() and Stream.ReadAsync() look like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok I found it!

```
    StorageFile storageFile =
      await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

    var randomAccessStream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();
    Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead();
```

Comment: Is possible convert the stream to StorageFile? :o

Comment: Thank you very much  ...You make my day :)
earlier trying to do randomAccessStream --> Byte[] --> memorystream  but it was not working properly.
always failing IRandomAccessStream -->  Byte[]
on below line 
DataReader.LoadAsync((uint)s.Size);

NOW work like a charm

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it in one less line:

```
Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```