# VS2013 Failure to load Resource file for Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am creating an app with customizable live tiles, and have some of my own, kind of marked up XML templates that I want to include with my project.

The XML files have been placed in `Assets/Tiles/FileName.xml`.

I am trying to use the following code to load the document:

```
XmlDocument tileXml = new XmlDocument();
tileXml.LoadXml("ms-appx:///Assets/Tiles/SM_Date.xml");
```

The file name exists as it does in the directory. Upon run, the application force quits, unable to find the file specified.

This is the only error I get in my Output

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in AppName.exe

[image]

How do I load an XML file from project Assets?

I have tried the following paths

> ms-appex:///Assets/Tile/SM_DAte.xml
>   ms-appx:///Assets...
>   ms-appex://Assets...
>   ms-appx://Assets...
>   /Assets...
>   Assets...
>   /Tiles...
>   Tiles...

All with no avail. I have checked the output directory, and the files are indeed being copied to and assets directory located at: `\bin\Debug\AppX\`

Trying to load it as a file also does not work:

```
using System.IO;
string xmlContent = File.ReadAllText("");
```

The above throws an error stating that File in undefined.

Comment: I thought I already has that in the tag. I am on a SurfacePro, running Windows8.1, developing an app for Windows8.1.

Comment: Have you made sure that the XML is valid? Also, try to save it in UTF without BOM in an external editor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was finally able to accomplis this by using the following code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Assets\Tiles\SM_Date.xml");
XmlDocument wideTileXml = new XmlDocument();
wideTileXml.LoadXml(xDoc.ToString());
```

To me, this seems like a bit of a workaround, as I have to load the XML as plain text, and then make an XmlDocument from the plain text XML...

A bit hackish, but for now, it does what I need. Thanks to all that helped.

Comment: The combination of XmlDoc and XDoc is ridiculous. But funny.

Comment: This is the ONLY way I could get it to work. With `using System.IO`, Visual Studio tells me that `File` is unknown.

Comment: Nonsense. RT has quite a different API sometimes, esp for I/O. But there must be an (async) way to load from an Uri. Why you prefer XmlDoc over XDoc beats me though.

Comment: Because the `TileNotification` constructor requires the use of `XmlDocument`. I am a Java developer trying my hand a C#...

Comment: @Downvoters. Instead of downvoting, how about you provide some constructive feedback? None of the answers posted have worked, so I found a workaround...

Comment: As I said in my update, I think you're just missing a way of loading from XmlDocument - have you tried `LoadFromFileAsync`?

Answer (score 3):

First try changing the path to "ms-appx" instead of "ms-appex".
If that doesn't work (and i expect so) try getting the Stream to the resource file and then call
the Load overloaded method on the XmlDocument that takes in a Stream.

See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965322.aspx
and here : [Getting a Stream from a resource file / content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856352/getting-a-stream-from-a-resource-file-content)

Comment: I mistyped my original question, I actually am using `ms-appx`. Please see the edit for an attached picture of the line of code that is erroring, the error itself, and the solution explorer.

Answer (score 2):

If @atomaras answer doesn't help, try setting the properties on the XML file as follows:

```
Build Action : Content
Copy to Output Directory : Copy Always or Copy if newer
```

Just checked, and XmlDocument doesn't seem to have an overload that loads a file - it accepts an XML string.  Try `LoadFromFileAsync` instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br206263

Comment: My Assets directory does not have this option. I assume it is set to be copied automatically.

Comment: The directory is indeed being copied to output.

Comment: Updated the post - I think your problem is trying to use `LoadXml`

Comment: You need an `IStorageFile` for `LoadFromFileAsync()`. FromUri looks more promising.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use "Assets\Tiles\FileName.xml" ?
Because sometimes using '\' instead of '/' helps on windows.