# How to load URIs like "ms-resource:///Files/somefile.svg"?

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, skiasharp

I have a file whose **Build action** is `Content`. I want to use it in a custom control:

```
<MyControl Source="dashes.svg" />
```

Inside my control, the Source property is defined as `Uri`

Whenever the `Uri` property changes, I want to load the **SVG** image that will be drawn in the bounds of the control using `SkiaSharp` (an `SKXamlCanvas`). The problem is that I don't know how to access the `Stream` of the Content using its `Uri`.

In run time, the Uri that I get is this:

**ms-resource:///Files/dashes.svg**

How do I use it to get the `Stream` of the Resource?
And most importantly, how do I get the `Stream` synchronously in order to avoid spreading async methods around? To say the truth, I don't know how could I transform my code into async.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, any string you pass to the URI property of your control will be prefixed with: "ms-resource:///Files/". The only way to get the corresponding file seems to be to replace "ms-resource:///Files/" with "ms-appx://".

### With async

You can get the `Stream` of a file using the following code snippet [copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856352/getting-a-stream-from-a-resource-file-content):

```cs
Uri uriFromDP= new Uri(oldUri.ToString().Replace("ms-resource:///Files/","ms-appx://"));
StorageFile storageFile = await 
 Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uriFromDP);

var randomAccessStream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();
Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead();
```

### Without async

To get around async/await, you can use this snippet:

```cs
Uri uriFromDP = new Uri(oldUri.ToString().Replace("ms-resource:///Files/","ms-appx://"));
StorageFile storageFile =
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uriFromDP).AsTask().Result;

var randomAccessStream = storageFile.OpenReadAsync().AsTask().Result;
Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead();
```

Edit: Update URI's and their creation

Comment: I've tried your code and it throws: dashes.svg not a valid absolute URI (ArgumentException)

Comment: BTW, I made a mistake! sorry: The build action of the file is set to **Content**.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think it should be `ms-appx` instead of `ms-resource`. I will update my answer.

Comment: Regarding the ms-resource kind of Uri. Please, do this: create a User Control, define a dependency property of type Uri and add a "changed handler" to it. In XAML, use that User Control and set the Uri properly to a Content file inside the project. Observe the value passed to the property. You will get "ms-resource:///Files/..."

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#ms-resource) the URI "ms-resource:///Files/dashes.svg" refers to a string definied in your resources, while the URI "ms-appx:///Files/dash.svg" refers to a file which is included inside your app. So "ms-appx://..." is the URI referring to the file.

Comment: Maybe you can try replacing "ms-resource" with "ms-appx" to get the corresponding file URI. How exactly are you setting the URI?